# How to fix invalid sender error using alchemy-sdk?

Tags: polygon, alchemy, alchemy-sdk

Trying to send a transaction with Alchemy-sdk, but I keep getting invalid sender.
What am I doing wrong or missing, code below:

**My provider is created using** `ethers.providers.JSONRPCProvider(alchemyurlincludingAPIKEY)`

```js
const PRIVATE_KEY = 'priv_key'
const config = {
  apiKey: 'api_string',
  network: Network.Polygon
}
const wallet2 = new Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY)
const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

const customContract = new ethers.Contract(
      signature.relay_address,
      customABI,
      provider
    );

    try {
      let tx:any = await customContract.populateTransaction.function(
        msg.from,
        .,
        .
        {
          type: 2,
          maxFeePerGas: Utils.parseUnits("200", "gwei"),
          maxPriorityFeePerGas: Utils.parseUnits("200", "gwei")

        }
      );
      tx.chainId = 137
      const signedTransaction = await wallet2.signTransaction(tx);
      const response = await alchemy.transact.sendTransaction(tx);
      new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        try {
          await alchemy.transact.waitForTransaction((response as Transaction).hash!.valueOf(), 2, 
      60000);
```

Response is this :

```js
{
jsonrpc:"2.0",
id:43,
error:{
code:-32000,
message:"invalid sender"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was this:

const config = {
apiKey: 'api_string',
**network: Network.MATIC_MAINNET**
}